# How to automatically adjust size of 2 side-by-side iframe using a this ratio?

Tags: html, css, iframe

I have this code:
There are two side-by-side iframes with the ratio shown in the link, I want it to keep that ratio in any screen size.
The first iframe is iframe2 and the second iframe is iframe 1.

```
<div class="box">
<iframe allow="camera; microphone; fullscreen; display-capture; autoplay" src="source 1" 
style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" frameborder="1" 
marginheight="0px" marginwidth="0px" height="600px" width="300px" align="right" 
allowfullscreen> </iframe>
</div>

<div class="box">
<iframe src="source 2" style="border:0px #ffffff none;" name="myiFrame" scrolling="no" 
frameborder="1" marginheight="0px" marginwidth="350px" height="600px" width="1033px" 
allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>


[The ratio should also look like this no matter what the screen size is 1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H7D81.png
```

How to automatically adjust size of 2 side-by-side iframe using a this ratio?
I know a little about the CSS and i tried to use it but the iframes size not adjusting instead become a small square, whenever I tried to use the methods given from other questions
Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try This

```css
.box {
    position: relative;
    float: left;
    padding-bottom: 38%;
    border: 5px solid #fff;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 70%;
}
.box.box2 {
    width: 30%;
}
.box iframe {
    position: absolute;
    width: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9xwazD5SyVg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>

<div class="box box2">
  <iframe width="1280" height="720" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/9xwazD5SyVg" title="YouTube video player" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

Comment: Oh, thank you this help, but there is a 15% white space at bottom of the screen

Comment: You can increase **padding-bottom** how much you want

Answer (score 0):

try using the aspect-ratio property in css... like this:

```
   iframe {aspect-ratio: 1/1;}
```

And one more thing. It's better to do the styling in a separate css file rather than inline styling